# How to change underline color error textinputlayout android

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

**I would like to know how to change the error color of the TextInputLayout underline.**

[image: TextInputLayout with error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `app:boxStrokeErrorColor` attribute:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        app:boxStrokeErrorColor="@color/primaryLightColor"
        ...>
```

[image]

It requires Material Components lirabry version `1.2.0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the color in the edittext background as such. This background makes the underline to disappear. But you can make it to whatever color you want.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            app:hintEnabled="false">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Floating Hint Disabled"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
```